# Creating todo list with vue js 3

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, vue.js

trying to learn Vue js and I'm building a Todo list app everything is working but I have a problem with something, for example when I click on active I want  to show the tasks that are not done or finished and so on, here is the code, I tried to use code snippet but it does not work because it does not support Vue js 3 yet

```html
<template>
  <section class="header">
  </section>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-theme">
      <h1>Todo</h1>
      <input  type="checkbox" id="switch-l" class="themeSwitch">
      <label @click="switchTheme" for="switch-l" id="switch" class="themeSwitch-label"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="todosInput">
      <div id="mark"></div>
      <form @submit.prevent="addNewTodo" class="form" action="" data-new-todo-form>
        <input v-model="newTodo" name="newTodo" id="todos" data-new-todo-input type="text" placeholder="Create a new todo..." >
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="myTodos">
      <ul id="todo-list">
        <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="todo.id" class="todo-item ">
          <input @click="toggleDone(todo)" class="js-tick" id="1610198328386" type="checkbox">
          <span :class="{ done: todo.done }">{{todo.task}}</span>
          <img @click="deleteTodo(index)" class="delete" width="15px" height="15px" src="/images/icon-cross.svg" alt="cross">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <p id="todosLeft">{{}}items left</p><!-- Add dynamic number -->
      <div class="controls-list-div">
        <ul class="controls-list" data-lists>
          <li id="All">All</li>
          <li id="Active">Active</li>
          <li id="Completed">Completed</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p id="Clear-completed">Clear Completed</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="instruc">
    <p>Drag and drop to reorder list</p>
  </div>


  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import {ref} from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const newTodo = ref('');
    const todos = ref([]);
    const addNewTodo = () => {
      todos.value.push({
        done: false,
        task: newTodo.value,
        id: Date.now(),
      });
      newTodo.value = ''
    }

    const toggleDone = (todo) => {
      todo.done = !todo.done
    }

    const deleteTodo = (index) => {
      todos.value.splice(index, 1)
    }

    const switchTheme = () => {
      const body = document.body
      if (body.classList.contains('light')) {
        body.classList.replace('light', 'dark')
      } else {
        body.classList.replace('dark', 'light')
      }
    }

    return {
      addNewTodo,
      newTodo,
      todos,
      toggleDone,
      deleteTodo,
      switchTheme,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of rendering `todos` in `v-for`, introduce `computed` (named maybe `filteredTodos`) and render that. Introduce new `ref` named `filter` with possible values of `all/active/completed`. Implement filtering inside `filteredTodos` based on the value of `filter`....

Comment: sorry, could you write it in code, I'm confused, I don't know how to render the todos with filtered todos, and I don't know how to connect the filter ref with each filter "all-completed-active".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering `todos` in `v-for`, introduce `computed` (named maybe `filteredTodos`) and render that. Introduce new `ref` named `filter` with possible values of all/active/completed. Implement filtering inside `filteredTodos` based on the value of `filter`...

```js
let app = Vue.createApp({  
  setup() {
    const newTodo = Vue.ref('');
    const filter = Vue.ref('all')
    const todos = Vue.ref([
      { task: "Task 1", done: false, id: 1 },
      { task: "Task 2", done: false, id: 2 }
    ]);
    
    const filteredTodos = Vue.computed(() => {
      const filterFn = filter.value === 'active' ? (item) => !item.done : 
        filter.value === 'completed' ? (item) => item.done : (item) => true;
      return todos.value.filter(filterFn)
    })
    
    const addNewTodo = () => {
      todos.value.push({
        done: false,
        task: newTodo.value,
        id: Date.now(),
      });
      newTodo.value = ''
    }

    const toggleDone = (todo) => {
      todo.done = !todo.done
    }

    const deleteTodo = (index) => {
      todos.value.splice(index, 1)
    }

    const switchTheme = () => {
      const body = document.body
      if (body.classList.contains('light')) {
        body.classList.replace('light', 'dark')
      } else {
        body.classList.replace('dark', 'light')
      }
    }

    return {
      addNewTodo,
      newTodo,
      todos,
      toggleDone,
      deleteTodo,
      switchTheme,      
      filter,
      filteredTodos
    }
  }
})

app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.5/vue.global.prod.js" integrity="sha512-7mjRUL9551cOFF57PSrURwSa9UsUmufUCU9icwUEoUrECcxpa20PakbPplb7b4ZGbCc0StIr9ytHoXH9+v6ygA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="myTodos">
    {{ filter }}
    <ul id="todo-list">
      <li v-for="(todo, index) in filteredTodos" :key="todo.id" class="todo-item ">
        <input @click="toggleDone(todo)" class="js-tick" id="1610198328386" type="checkbox" :checked="todo.done">
        <span :class="{ done: todo.done }">{{todo.task}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <ul class="controls-list" data-lists>
      <li id="All"><a @click="filter = 'all'" href="#">All<a/></li>
      <li id="Active"><a @click="filter = 'active'" href="#">Active<a/></li>
      <li id="Completed"><a @click="filter = 'completed'" href="#">Completed<a/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it shows me an error "item Is defined but never used"

Comment: Prolly just an ESLint error you can easily ignore or rewrite `(item) => true` into `() => true`. But the code is just fine as you can see if you run the snippet...